# How to delete the grepped iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, bash, linux-networking, shell-scripting

I have iptables starting from `cali-`

```
 root@Ubuntu-18-VM:~# iptables -S | grep -oP '(?<!^:)cali-[^ ]+'
    cali-FORWARD
    cali-INPUT
    cali-OUTPUT
    cali-cidr-block
    cali-from-hep-forward
    cali-from-host-endpoint
    cali-from-wl-dispatch
    cali-from-wl-dispatch-5
    cali-fw-cali2847b154969
    cali-fw-cali4bb24809f90
    cali-fw-cali531f8f2e712
    cali-fw-cali5a82b3ff301
    cali-pri-_CVSZITRyIpEmH8AB6H
    cali-pri-_HayIXLB85hzHkIhWER
    cali-pri-_PTRGc0U-L5Kz7V6ERW
    cali-pri-_u2Tn2rSoAPffvE7JO6
    cali-pri-kns.kube-system
    cali-pro-_CVSZITRyIpEmH8AB6H
    cali-pro-_HayIXLB85hzHkIhWER
    cali-pro-_PTRGc0U-L5Kz7V6ERW
    cali-pro-_u2Tn2rSoAPffvE7JO6
    cali-pro-kns.kube-system
    cali-to-hep-forward
    cali-to-host-endpoint
    cali-to-wl-dispatch
    cali-to-wl-dispatch-5
    cali-tw-cali2847b154969
    cali-tw-cali4bb24809f90
    cali-tw-cali531f8f2e712
    cali-tw-cali5a82b3ff301
    cali-wl-to-host
```

How can I delete these 31 iptables ? After grep what delete command shall I add so that `iptables -S` command didn't show the `cali-` iptables ?

Comment: You cannot do in simple way like this. IPTables refuses to delete a chain if some other chain references it.

This means that you have to first verify that there are no jumps to a particular chain before deleting the chain.

Comment: I'll extend that suggestion. Change grep expression for it to catch `-j cali-[\S]+` first. Remove those rules. Then there'll be no references to your said chains, so you'll be able to flush and then remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Deleting calico-Iptables:**

Use [calico-policy](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/hack/remove-calico-policy/remove-calico-policy.sh) and add below lines at the end of script:

```
echo "Flush remaining calico iptables"
iptables-save | grep -i cali | iptables -F

echo "Delete remaining calico iptables"
iptables-save | grep -i cali | iptables -X
```

This will delete all calico iptables when you check with `iptables -S`

**Note:** Run this script only after uninstalling K3S.

**Deleting calicoctl:**

Simply run `sudo rm $(which calicoctl)` command, it will find and delete the calicoctl.